# Why do I get an "unexpected token" error when parsing JSON using Ruby's json gem?

Tags: ruby, json, nokogiri

The JSON object I'm parsing is at http://api.4chan.org/3/catalog.json

Here is my Ruby code:

```
['open-uri','nokogiri','json'].each{|g| require g}

json_test = File.open('json_test.JSON','r').read
board_cat_body = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://api.4chan.org/3/catalog.json'))

puts JSON.parse(board_cat_body)
```

Result (it's very long so I took a part of it out):

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse': 387: unexpected token at '{"no":248019,"sticky":1,"closed":1,"now":"12\/19....
```

However, if I copy and paste the contents of http://api.4chan.org/3/catalog.json into a local JSON file and parse from that local JSON file, there is no problem.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you sticking the json through an HTML parser?

Comment: I've never before read a JSON file from the web using Ruby.

Comment: Write `File.open('json_test.JSON','r').read` as `File.read('json_test.JSON')`. And, `JSON.parse(...)` can be written like `JSON[...]` if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Nokogiri call. JSON isn't HTML.

```
['open-uri','json'].each{|g| require g}
json = JSON.parse(open('http://api.4chan.org/3/catalog.json').read)
puts json.inspect
```

Comment: Ah, so in this case, the correct way is to open and read the '.json' file using the same method as I would if I was opening and reading a local file?

Comment: The open-uri library enables you to "open" a URI as if it were a file and read from it. It doesn't work for everything, but does work in this case. Remember, the request may fail from time to time, so you should look at rescuing from that scenario.

Comment: Got it. I'll make sure to watch out for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The document you get in `board_cat_body` is not a JSON doc, it's HTML, as you can see if you print it. So, I propose to download the document this way:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = URI.parse('http://api.4chan.org/3/catalog.json')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http| http.request(req) }
```

and parse it:

```
puts JSON.parse(res.body)
```

Comment: This method also works (once I include `require 'json'`), though it is a few more lines than @stef's.

Comment: yes, but you get a higher level of control if any kind of error occurs in the download file phase, and the oportunity of catch them and handle in the right way

Comment: For this, OpenURI would be more than adequate, as it automatically handles redirects which Net::HTTP won't do without more code.